# How to make a "DontDestoryOnLoad" Object remember objects from original scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game where the music game objects starts on the main menu scene and it has two components slider that I placed with drag and drop

[image]

and the player can interact with those sliders on the settings canvas in that scene. when the player changes scene the music keeps playing because of DontDestroyOnLoad and that's great! but if the player returns to the main scene the dontdestroy game object that plays music forgets

[image]

the sliders and the sliders don't do anything because they are not connected to the music game object with the dontdestroy. any way I can get around this?

Comment: You can't except those are also not destroyed ... Why not rather use e.g. `PlayerPrefs` to pass the values along your scenes and don't reference them at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the slider that your music manager is referencing is destroyed.

**Solution 1**

To quickly fix the issue, simply set those sliders as `DontDestroyOnLoad` as well. When you don't want the slider to show, just create two game objects variables and drop those sliders in. Then use `gameobject.setactive(true/false)` to turn it on or off

**Solution 2**

Create a function that triggers every scene change, and inside that function, help the sound manager to locate the slider by using find gameobject with tag, and inside the editor give those sliders gameobject a tag so it can be easily located. In this case, even the slider get destroyed the sound manager can still reference the new sliders

Comment: Solution 3: if these are logically related, regardless of scenes and you want them "everywhere", then add all of them to a GameObject (or create a prefab), and make their parent `DontDestroyOnLoad` (this is just a little bit "maybe" elegant version of Solution 1, depending on usecase)